# Oauth2 latest distribution of Leeloo / Apache Amber

Tags: java, oauth-2.0

I'Ve been looking around for a while, I'm not familiar with this project and it seems to be in a bit of flux right now, I'm wondering if anyone knows what is really going on and what the recommended way is to hook into the project at this point. Shouldn't there particular tags within Amber that co-incide with the Leeloo 0.1, for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for late answer, I hope it is still relevant.

You can build Amber OAuth 2.0 package from sources: https://github.com/apache/amber/tree/138ffbeeee3893013f22c3be35892bec5ac0a36a/oauth-2.0 and documentation is provided on: leeloo.smartam.net

We are currently working on releasing Amber 0.1 package and documentation. These will be released soon.